# MFC and embedded databases?

Tags: database, mfc

Can you recommend good embedded databases with Visual C++/MFC?

I've looked at:
- SQLite
- HamsterDB

Any others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look around on codeproject.com for MFC-esque wrappers around sqlite. There are quite a number of good ones. The sqlite website has links to c++ wrappers, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SQL Server Compact Edition plus ATL OLE DB Consumer Templates (you can use them with MFC).

This is an interesting link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/atl_ole_db_ppc.aspx

You have to use this OLE DB provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174142(SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Windows has an embedded database enginge (no query engine, a low level API like HamsterDB).

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151222121218/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/windowssdk/archive/2008/10/23/esent-extensible-storage-engine-api-in-the-windows-sdk.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i'm the author of hamsterdb.

To answer your question - it depends.

sqlite offers more functionality, but is slower.

hamsterdb (or tokyo cabinet, or berkeleydb) are faster but have less functionality.

if you give a better description of your use case then i can help better.

bye
Christoph

Comment: hi Christoph, I like your HamsterDB, but it needs to be bit more functional. For instance, no SQL parser, no easy way to get/set data.

Comment: Sure - it's just a key/value store and not an SQL database. The functionality is very limited, but you get a lot of performance and do not need to administrate a database.